# clear ListView item selection Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

I have listView called "Main_Menu" in Navigation Page. When I click it, it shows other page. When I return to Page with Main_Menu, I want do clear selection.
Please help me. Thanks

P.S

```
((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
```

causes crash when it onAppear() or onDisappear();

Comment: Sorry if I'm way off base as I don't know if the xamarin.forms would make a difference, but can you set `((ListView)sender).SelectedIndex = -1;`

Comment: where exactly is this line of code?

Comment: ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null; I tried put it onAppear() and onDisappear()

Comment: "sender" does not have any context in OnAppearing or OnDisappearing.

Comment: I know. I finaly found a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution:

```
 if (e.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            return;
        }
((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to set the SelectedItem with the ItemSelected event handler. Add the eventhandler to your XAML file and then add the event handler to its code behind.

```
<!-Page.xaml-/>
<ListView x:Name="myList"   
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
    HasUnevenRows="true"
    ItemSelected="OnItemSelected"/>

// in your code behind Page.xaml.cs
void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (sender!= null && sender is ListView listview)
   {
       if (e != null)  e.SelectedItem = null;
   }
}
```

Comment: When you select an item the SelectionMode=None should unselect the item after you tapped it. There is no way how to prevent selection of items in the first place unless you want to create your own control/renderer.

Comment: I updated my answer. It now shows how to reset the SelectItem to null if the user selects an item. Again, it will select the CellView first and then unselect the item. Best you can do with Xamarin.Forms ListView